# Deliting all instances of a css class with Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have global variables:

```
          units = 0;
          majorUnits = 0; 
          supportUnits = 0;
          requiredUnits = 0;
          electiveUnits = 0;
          electiveUnitsStop = 0;
          pending = 0;
          percent = 0;
          supportPercent = 0;
          requiredPercent = 0;
          electivePercent = 0;
```

I use this variables on function:

```
      $("tr").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("taken");
        if ( $(this).hasClass('taken') ) 
        { .....
```

Then I have a second function in which I set variables back to zero:

```
      $( "#clear-button" ).click(function() {
          units = 0;
          majorUnits = 0; 
          supportUnits = 0;
          requiredUnits = 0;
          electiveUnits = 0;
          electiveUnitsStop = 0;
          pending = 0;
          percent = 0;
          supportPercent = 0;
          requiredPercent = 0;
          electivePercent = 0;
          // $( "tr" ).click(); 
          //$("tr").find('taken').removeClass('taken');
          //$("table").closest('tr').find('.taken').removeClass('taken');
          //$("tr").removeClass();
          //taken.allInstances = [];
        });
```

As seen above in commented code I'm trying to remove all occurrences of
class `taken` that might or might not be present in the rows of my html table.

How could I accomplish this ?!?!

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to remove the **class** or the **element**?

Remove class from sub elements:

```
$('table#tablename .taken').removeClass('taken');
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Remove elements completely:

```
$('table#tablename .taken').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Also, depending on your HTML structure you could be more specific with your targetting and use `this` instead of specifying the table name (also using `find`, `closest` etc)